# Can't import any functions from module named 'code'

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I created a module named code: code.py and wrote a simple function:

```
def main():
    print("simple function")
```

I tried dropping this file inside site-packages and when I run:

```
import code
code.main()
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'main'.

Interestingly enough, if I rename the module to foo.py, this code works just fine:

```
import foo
foo.main()
```

Code isn't a reserved word so why can't I name a module code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`code`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) is a Python module already, that is what is being imported, not your file

Comment: I actually had no idea of existence of this module. Turns out there's a couple in the [python module index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) that I might conceivably use without knowing.

Comment: Really nice pointing out the python module index. There are a bunch of pretty "common" names in there that I would most likely use without noticing. That's most likely why we should always install modules inside a package, to avoid name conflicts.